# Synchronise interface names attached to IP addresses between host Ubuntu and QEMU guest Ubuntu

Tags: 22.04, qemu, network-bridge, ping

I've set up a second bridge on QEMU using a bridge named `virbr1`. In my host OS I have:

```
virbr1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.100.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
```

In the guest I have:

```
enp10s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
         inet 192.168.100.139  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
```

I can ping from Host to Guest and vice versa by using the IP addresses, but how do I make these names available to both sides so I can ping by name instead?